# Theads to keep alive a process but useless otherwise

Tags: c#, com

Hello guys I have a question regardless a old code a client needed a update.

This code add a thread.sleep(500) to keep the service alive, is reading from a com port some calls, and sending a alarm to other pcs now this time when I was sending some information to the machine in question this error pops out

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'textBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

```
    private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        string data = port.ReadExisting();
        //try
        //{
            if (textBox1.TextLength == 30000)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }
        //}
        //catch (Exception) {}
        this.BeginInvoke(new setTextDeleg(si_DataRecived), new object[]{
        data});
    }
```

This is the function that writes on the com machine, does making a exception to eat the error is ok, or is there another better way to handle it?

PD: Sorry for my bad english, this is on C# 2008 vs

Comment: You are already using BeginInvoke like you have to, I don't get the point of the question.  The Sleep() call is *very* ugly, it isn't actually reliable.  Just buffer the pieces of the string you get.

Comment: I guess, I did this code years ago I am just updating it but I agree, I have a question, the com port is virtulized, if I remove the thread.sleep it seems it tries to go back to com1 for some reason any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should modify GUI components like textboxes and labels only from the thread that created them which is the main thread. You may take a look at [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) which simplifies this task in WinForms application. And here's another [useful article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=VS.100).aspx) illustrating the usage of the [InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) property and the [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to simply swallow this exception.  The exception is occurring because you are not allowed to modify UI components from any thread other than the UI thread (the thread that created them).  Instead, check out [this MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/17/91685.aspx) article on how to pass information between worker threads (your thread that sleeps) and UI threads to update the text box in the correct manner.

Comment: Thanks a lot seems like this is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because Windows Forms Controls are not thread-safe, and it would seem that the control is not being invoked properly for a thread-safe call. You can use the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class or you can [invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=VS.80).aspx) it yourself. Here is a small code example.

```
    // Delegate used by our worker thread to invoke our control
    private delegate void ProgressDelegate(int value);

    // Callback method used for our delegate
    private void ProgressCallback(int value) {
        progressBar1.Value = value;
    }

    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyThreadWorker));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    // Thread method
    private void MyThreadWorker() {
        // Setup the delegate
        ProgressDelegate mydelegate = new ProgressDelegate(ProgressCallback);

        // Do some work
        int pos = 0;
        do {
            pos++;

            // Make a thread-safe call to our control and invoke our callback on the original thread
            // Original thread: The thread the form and control were created on
            progressBar1.Invoke(mydelegate, pos);
        } while (pos < 100);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what some of your other code looks like, but you could probably move this

```
 if (textBox1.TextLength == 30000)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "";
        }
```

to the `si_DataRecived` method, so that it gets executed as part of the `BeginInvoke` call, the target of which will execute on the main (UI) thread.